# jQuery is escaping my post data

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I prevent jQuery escaping my XML data? I use get the content from the a div (content is XML) but it escapes it when posting. This is the output:

> \n    \n\n    \n        123\n   \n

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $(".data").html();

    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        dataType: "text",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,   
        data: {
            xml: data
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `var data = JSON.stringify($(".data").html(););` try stringify the html.

Comment: When I apply that the output is: \"\\n\\t<products>123</products>\\n\\t\\n\"

Comment: Can you show us your HTML? `.html()` should return the structure as a string without escaping anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the leading and trailing whitespace by using the `trim` function:

```
var data = $(".data").html();
data = data.trim(' ');
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2k6gp9ru/

For the quotes you can do the following to unescape the quotes:

```
var quotes = '/"';
var reg = new RegExp(quotes,'g');
var str = '/"Hallo/"';
str = str.replace(reg,'"');
```

Here is the fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/2k6gp9ru/1/

Comment: That indeed solves the problem for a simple node: <products>123</products>. But when the XML contains quotes it'll escape them.

Comment: Thnx, isn't there a better workaround? Since it contains just for than those character, it contains also other characters such as ! etc.

Comment: Can you post an example of the data that you're getting?

Comment: It's dynamic but this is a small part of it:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Products>
     
        <Product>
     <Unieke-Code>16120</Unieke-Code>
     <Titel><![CDATA[Text -  Text - 3000 gr.]]></Titel>
     <Prijs>14.35</Prijs>
     <Deeplink>
      <![CDATA[
       url
      ]]>
     </Deeplink>
     <Image>url</Image>
     
     <ModelCode>16046</ModelCode>
     <Variant-Code>10207</Variant-Code>

     <Categorie><![CDATA[
         >  > 
        ]]>
     </Categorie>
     <Omschrijving>
      <![CDATA[
       <p><strong>Text</strong><br />
<br />

Answer (score 0):

Since your content isn't HTML just use text() to get the contents of the div.

```
var data = $(".data").text()
```

Comment: I think the point is they want (not escaped) XML, not just the raw content.

Comment: Exactly, I just want the entire XML (including quotes etc. without escaping)